# Double Repeater cloning content in textarea

Tags: php, wordpress, repeater, custom-post-type, meta-boxes

I am busy building a custom post type with repeater metaboxes (sorting and cloning) for storing groups of information.

The first repeater metabox is a single text input and works perfectly.

The problem child:
The second repeater metabox is a double repeater with a text input for the label and a textarea for the content. The data saves and sorts, however when I click the clone button the textarea inherits the value of the last item on the list. This value can be overwritten but when I remove the row it removes the content from the row above as well.

I suspect the issue might be with the row counting. On investigation I found that the new row had the same [number] as the one above. I am unfortunately stumped as to how to fix this and the Codex hasn't yielded much answers.

```
function show_country_facts_meta_box() {
    global $facts_meta_fields, $post;
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="facts_meta_box_nonce" value="'.wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)).'" />';
    echo '<table class="form-table">';
    foreach ($facts_meta_fields as $field) {
        $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);
        echo '<tr>
                <td style="display: inline-block; width: 100%; padding: 0;">';
                switch($field['type']) {
                    case 'double_repeatable':
                        echo ' <ul id="'.$field['id'].'-repeatable" class="custom_repeatable">';
                        $i = 0;
                        if ($meta) {
                            foreach($meta as $row) {
                                echo '<li>
                                    <span class="sort hndle">|||</span>
                                    <div class="rowMiddle">
                                        <label>'.$field['options'][0].'</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="'.$field['id'].'['.$i.'][0]" id="'.$field['id'].'" value="'.$row[0].'" size="15"/>
                                        <label>'.$field['options'][1].'</label>
                                        <textarea name="'.$field['id'].'['.$i.'][1]" id="'.$field['id'].'" cols="60" rows="4">'.$row[1].'</textarea>
                                    </div>
                                    <a class="repeatable-remove button" href="#">&#8211;</a>
                                </li>';
                                $i++;
                            }
                        } else {
                            echo '<li>
                                <span class="sort hndle">|||</span>
                                <div class="rowMiddle">
                                    <label>'.$field['options'][0].'</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="'.$field['id'].'['.$i.'][0]" id="'.$field['id'].'" value="'.$row[0].'" size="15"/>
                                    <label>'.$field['options'][1].'</label>
                                    <textarea name="'.$field['id'].'['.$i.'][1]" id="'.$field['id'].'" cols="60" rows="4"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <a class="repeatable-remove button" href="#">&#8211;</a>
                            </li>';
                        }
                        echo '</ul>
                            <span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span><br />
                            <a style="margin-top:10px;" class="repeatable-add button" href="#">+</a>';
                    break;
                } 
        echo '</td></tr>';
    } 
    echo '</table>'; 
}
```

```
// saving the repeater
function save_facts_custom_meta($post_id) {
    global $facts_meta_fields;
    if ( !isset( $_POST['facts_meta_box_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['facts_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__) ) )
        return $post_id;
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
        return $post_id;
    if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {
        if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id))
            return $post_id;
        } elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
            return $post_id;
    }
    foreach ($facts_meta_fields as $field) {
        $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);
        $new = $_POST[$field['id']];
        if($field['type'] == 'repeatable')
            $new = array_values($new);
        if ($new && $new != $old) {
            update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);
        } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {
            delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);
        }
    } 
}
add_action('save_post', 'save_facts_custom_meta');
```

Can anyone shed some light on how I can fix this?

Comment: I initially thought the issue was with the counting but seems it is actually with the textarea.

If I replace this -
`
<textarea name="'.$field['id'].'['.$i.'][1]" id="'.$field['id'].'" cols="60" rows="4"></textarea>
`

with this -
`
<input type="text" name="'.$field['id'].'['.$i.'][1]" id="'.$field['id'].'" value="'.$row[1].'" size="15"/>
`

The problem is solved except I really need it to be a textarea.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: The issue was in the jQuery.

The script was counting the inputs but not the textarea - including this form field solved the issue.